# Read JSON files using dataset schema

Tags: json, types, dataset, schema, palantir-foundry

This is a JSON file which is added into a Foundry dataset:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Tim",
    "born": "2000 01 01",
    "location": {"country": "UK", "city": "London"},
    "scores": [
      {"date": "2022 02 01", "score": 4},
      {"date": "2022 03 01", "score": 4}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Kim",
    "born": "1999 12 31",
    "location": {"country": "LT", "city": "Vilnius"},
    "scores": [
      {"date": "2022 02 01", "score": 3},
      {"date": "2022 03 01", "score": 5}
    ]
  }
]
```

The dataset currently has no schema, so preview only shows the file:

[image: JSON file without schema]

How to add the schema so that we could preview the JSON file?

**Data types:**
"name": *string*
"born": *date*
"location": *map*
"scores": *array of structs* ("date": *date*, "score": *integer*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read JSON files, `"multiline"` option must be set to `true`.
(If it was JSONL file, `"multiline"` option is not needed, i.e. it's `false`.)

For *map*, `"mapKeyType"` and `"mapValueType"` must be filled.
For *array*, `"arraySubtype"` must be filled.
For *struct*, `"subSchemas"` must be filled.
For *date*, `"dateFormat"` option may be needed if it's not `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

Setting everything up correctly will result in this preview:

[image: JSON file with schema added]

The schema used:

```json
{
  "fieldSchemaList": [
    {
      "type": "STRING",
      "name": "name",
      "nullable": null,
      "userDefinedTypeClass": null,
      "customMetadata": {},
      "arraySubtype": null,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "subSchemas": null
    },
    {
      "type": "DATE",
      "name": "born",
      "nullable": null,
      "userDefinedTypeClass": null,
      "customMetadata": {},
      "arraySubtype": null,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "subSchemas": null
    },
    {
      "type": "MAP",
      "name": "location",
      "nullable": null,
      "userDefinedTypeClass": null,
      "customMetadata": {},
      "arraySubtype": null,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mapKeyType": {
        "type": "STRING",
        "name": null,
        "nullable": null,
        "userDefinedTypeClass": null,
        "customMetadata": {},
        "arraySubtype": null,
        "precision": null,
        "scale": null,
        "mapKeyType": null,
        "mapValueType": null,
        "subSchemas": null
      },
      "mapValueType": {
        "type": "STRING",
        "name": null,
        "nullable": null,
        "userDefinedTypeClass": null,
        "customMetadata": {},
        "arraySubtype": null,
        "precision": null,
        "scale": null,
        "mapKeyType": null,
        "mapValueType": null,
        "subSchemas": null
      },
      "subSchemas": null
    },
    {
      "type": "ARRAY",
      "name": "scores",
      "nullable": null,
      "userDefinedTypeClass": null,
      "customMetadata": {},
      "arraySubtype": {
        "type": "STRUCT",
        "name": null,
        "nullable": null,
        "userDefinedTypeClass": null,
        "customMetadata": {},
        "arraySubtype": null,
        "precision": null,
        "scale": null,
        "mapKeyType": null,
        "mapValueType": null,
        "subSchemas": [
          {
            "type": "DATE",
            "name": "date",
            "nullable": null,
            "userDefinedTypeClass": null,
            "customMetadata": {},
            "arraySubtype": null,
            "precision": null,
            "scale": null,
            "mapKeyType": null,
            "mapValueType": null,
            "subSchemas": null
          },
          {
            "type": "INTEGER",
            "name": "score",
            "nullable": null,
            "userDefinedTypeClass": null,
            "customMetadata": {},
            "arraySubtype": null,
            "precision": null,
            "scale": null,
            "mapKeyType": null,
            "mapValueType": null,
            "subSchemas": null
          }
        ]
      },
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "subSchemas": null
    }
  ],
  "primaryKey": null,
  "dataFrameReaderClass": "com.palantir.foundry.spark.input.DataSourceDataFrameReader",
  "customMetadata": {
    "format": "json",
    "options": {
      "multiline": true,
      "dateFormat": "yyyy MM dd"
    }
  }
}
```

[Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html) one can find available file reading options, including reading from JSON files.